# Strange unstopable Do-While cycle in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a strange problem.
Want to create a script that input user to insert a string and than loop again in the input request until leaved blank.

The script work well in PowerGUI continuing prompting a input request until i press only [Enter] than the script go on.
The problem appear when i try to use the script on a powershell shell.
Pressing only [Enter] let the DoWhile cycle continue to prompt me the input request without possibility to stop it unless CTRL-Z it.

Some ideas to why?

```
[Int] $num = 1
[Array] $conts = @()

do {
    $a = read-host "Indirizzo mail Contatto $num`?"
    if ($a -ne $null) {
            $num++
            $conts += $a
    } 

} while($a -ne $null)

Function CreaContatto {
    $mailContact = $args 
    $aliasContact = $args -replace ("@","_")
    New-MailContact -ExternalEmailAddress $mailContact -Name $mailContact -Alias $aliasContact
}

ForEach ($cont in $conts) {CreaContatto $cont}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that PowerGUI implements a custom host and that returns null from `read-host` when there is no input. The standard PowerShell host doesn't do that, it returns an empty string (unless you hit ctrl-z which signals end-of-file). Since both are falsy you can do this:

```
do {
    $a = read-host "Indirizzo mail Contatto $num`?"
    if ($a) {
        $num++
        $conts += $a
    }
} while($a)
```

Comment: Many thanks. You are right about PowerGUI return.
Analysing the variable value during the script run your supposition are right. PowerGUI assign the $null value when string are empty. Probably Powershell doesn't do.

Answer (score 2):

Thing is, `$a` is not null when pressing Enter, it is a newline. You can see this if you add a `write-host $a` below your `if` statement.

In this case, I'd suggest using a regex:

```
do {
    $a = read-host "Indirizzo mail Contatto $num`?"
    if ($a -ne $null) {
            $num++
            $conts += $a
    } 

} while($a -match '.+')
```

This says that `$a` has to be one or more characters.

Comment: Your answer is right but for simplicity I choose the "mike z" one.
Need to implement more right answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: That's the correct one to choose, it's more accurate than mine. Upvoted it myself!